# How to solve the problem when install tensorflow：HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to install tensorflow by user account in centos. I use the command:
`python3 -m pip install tensorflow --user`
But I get the error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out
```

I've tried `curl "https://files.pythonhosted.org"`; there is no problem, I can get some data.
So my machine can access the website, But what's wrong with my install command?

Answer (score 3):

use timeout option.

here is command

```
python -m pip install --default-timeout=100 tensorflow --user
```